# Redirect CNAME with path

Tags: redirect, dns, cname

I have old domain (bar.com), and new domain (foo.com). I want to redirect bar.com/path to foo.com/path by DNS only. Is it possible?

Other question:
Now I can make CNAME to redirect from *.bar.com to foo.com. But is possible if we can make redirect from *.bar.com/path to foo.com/path?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a complete different protocol to HTTP. It will not trigger any redirects nor does it know anything about URLs or paths.

Comment: DNS is just a database. Just because it's not HTTP, doesn't mean it cannot contain information that is intended for HTTP to handle. See for example SRV records which contain information for UDP/TCP to handle. Those aren't layer 3 either.